# I am having issues importing react instagram in my project

Tags: reactjs

I installed it using `npm i react-instagram-embed`. It however gave me an error when i tried importing it in my project using the command:

```
import InstagramEmbed from 'react-instagram-embed.
```

It return the error below

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/home/marcos/Desktop/REACT/Instagram-clone/instagram/node_modules/react-instagram-embed/es'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
```

Comment: There's a typo in your import statement.

Comment: Kindly come up again, would you mind elaborating

Comment: I get you assume the missing closing quote, I missed it when posting the question

Comment: Did you try any of the various solutions proposed in the actual error message?

Comment: yes i did, I'm kind of new to react so i'm having some issues resolving such bugs